# Assigning css class to a particular block

Tags: blocks, theming

I want to add a CSS class to a particular block. I am using the module Block Class for it as shown in [block_class](http://drupal.org/project/block_class) module. I am able to enable the module and assign the class by going to structures/block/configure. I am facing problem in where to add the php snippet. I am using a Zen starter kit theme and have copied the block.tpl.php from Zen/templates to my theme/templates and added the lines as specified...

Here's what my code looks like:

Before:

```
<div id="<?php print $block_html_id; ?>" 
class="<?php print $classes;   ?>"
<?php print $attributes; ?>>
```

After:

```
<div id="<?php print $block_html_id; ?>" 
class="<?php print $classes; ?> **<?php print block_class($block);** ?>"
<?php print $attributes; ?>>
```

Comment: version d6 or d7?

Comment: I am using version 7

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you don't have to add any code to use the class you set on structure/block/configure. The class should be automatically added to $classes array.

Comment: even i thought so but when i am inspecting the element its not showing...i have cleared all cache also